# Correct way to alias non-g-prefixed commands and manpages

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, zsh

Homebrew always tells us that, when we install a package, if we want non-`g`-prefixed versions of commands like `grep(1)` and `sed(1)`, we should stick `/usr/local/opt/[command]/libexec/gnubin` up in front of our `$PATH`. But I use at least 4 Homebrew packages - `grep`, `sed`, `xargs`, and `find` - for which I want non-`g`-prefixed commands, and I don't want to make `$PATH` that long.

So I have logic in my shell rc files that creates a symlink from `g[command]` to `[command]` within the `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX` directory. Same goes for the manpages: when I type `man grep`, I want to see the manpage for the version of `grep(1)` that I'm actually running, namely GNU grep; I don't want to have to remember to type `man ggrep`. So then I create a symlink from `/usr/local/share/man/man1/g[command].1` to `[command].1` in the same directory.

The full rc-file logic is below:

```
    for cmd in ggrep gsed gxargs gfind; do
        cmd_path=${brew_bin}/${cmd}

        # the command with the leading 'g' stripped off
        new_cmd=${cmd#g}
        new_cmd_path=${brew_bin}/${new_cmd}
        if [[ -L $cmd_path ]]; then
            if [[ ! -e $new_cmd_path ]]; then
                ln -s $cmd_path $new_cmd_path
            fi
        fi

        # This logic will have to become more elaborate
        # if I ever start using non-g-prefixed GNU tools
        # apart from those in man chapter 1.
        man_dir='/usr/local/share/man/man1'
        if [ -d $man_dir ]; then
            old_man_filename="${cmd}.1"
            new_man_filename="${new_cmd}.1"
            pushd $man_dir >/dev/null
            if [ -e $old_man_filename ] && [ ! -e $new_man_filename ]; then
                echo "Linking $new_man_filename to $old_man_filename"
                ln -s $old_man_filename $new_man_filename
            fi
            popd >/dev/null
        fi
    done
```

Is this the best way to do it? It feels a bit ugly, and I'm always hesitant to commingle my own symlinks with those of a package manager like Homebrew. Is there some more elegant/widely accepted way? In particular, my method doesn't work for `curl`, which doesn't follow the same directory conventions as `grep`, `sed`, `find`, etc.

(Leave aside the question of whether it's advisable to put GNU grep ahead of the system grep in `$PATH`. I know the risks there. I actually filed a bug with Apple a while back to have one of the bash/zsh scripts explicitly specify `/usr/bin/[whichever_command]` rather than just `whichever_command`, because I think a lot of people put the Homebrew `$PATH` ahead of the system one.)

Comment: What's your objection to adding 4 paths to `PATH`?

Comment: BTW, this is a problem you don't have if you decamp from Homebrew for [Nix](https://nixos.org/), which doesn't prefix its coreutils commands.

Comment: `alias -g grep=ggrep`? It's a global alias, so in addition to working with calls to  `grep`, `man grep` will find the `ggrep` man page. You can use backslash to temporarily disable it (`print \grep`).

Comment: Just my personal opinion: If you decide to have for **some** commands to use the gnu-version automatically, but for some other commands to explicitly require the use of 'g'  to invoke the Gnu version, won't this be confusing and hard to remember? I decided for my Mac to keep the Gnu commands under their own name, in order to not break shell scripts written for the Mac (i.e. assuming BSD-commands). If you have to port scripts from Linux to the Mac, installing them under the Linux name may be an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the differences between the Gnu-Versions of the commands and the BSD-versions is mostly a problem when porting shell scripts: The commands do behave differently, and scripts written with BSD (MacOS) in mind expect the BSD-behaviour while scripts written for Gnu (Linux).

My suggestion therefore goes like this: Just stick with the Gnu commands under the Gnu-name. Since you (reasonably) have `/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH, you can on the command line decide, whether you want to use i.e. `find` or `gfind` or whatever.

In addition, I suggest that you create a new directory, for instance `$HOME/gnubin`, in which you place symbolic links for **all** of your gnu files:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gfind ~/gnubin/find
```

Now whenever you have/write a shell script originally written for Linux, you invoke it with your `gnubin` at the start of your PATH:

```
PATH=~/bin/gnubin:"$PATH" gnuscript.sh
```

If you are writing such a script, which is using Gnu tools, and from this script want to execute another script, which was written for BSD tools, you invoke it as

```
PATH=/bin:"$PATH" bsdscript.sh
```